# $O$ is not dense in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

$A$ is a matrix of order $n$, and $x$ is an $n$-dimensional column vector. The set
$$
O=\{x,Ax,A^2x,\cdots,A^mx,\cdots\}
$$
Prove that, $O$ is not dense in $\mathbb R^n$.

This claim *seems* to be trivial: it just *looks like* $\mathbb N$ in $\mathbb R$. I recalled how we verify the denseness of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$, but it seeems that the same method doesn't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: I guess that there are a lot of possible way to prove it.
A way to see it is: the limit of $\|A^mx\|$ can be infinite, or it may converge to a real number. In either case, the set is not dense

Comment: Could you expand on the details?

Comment: @FFjet If $\|A^m\| \to \infty$, then there are only finitely many elements in the unit ball centered at zero. If $\|A^m\|$ has upper bound $M$, then there are no elements outside the closed ball of radius $M$ centered at $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $O=\{A^mx:m\in\mathbb N_0\}$ is dense in $\mathbb R$. There are two possibilities:

1. $A^T$ has a real eigenvector $y$ corresponding to a real eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then
   \begin{aligned}
   &\ O=\{A^mx:m\in\mathbb N_0\}\text{ is dense in $\mathbb R^n$}\\
   \Rightarrow&\ y^TO=\{\lambda^m y^Tx:m\in\mathbb N_0\}\text{ is dense in $\mathbb R$}\\
   \Rightarrow&\ Y=\{\lambda^m:m\in\mathbb N_0\}\text{ is dense in $\mathbb R$}.
   \end{aligned}
2. $A^T=A^\ast$ has an eigevector $z$ corresponding to some non-real eigenvalue $\overline{\lambda}$. Then the $\mathbb R$-linear span of the entries of $z$ must be two-dimensional and hence it is equal to $\mathbb C$. Therefore,
   \begin{aligned}
   &\ O=\{A^mx:m\in\mathbb N_0\}\text{ is dense in $\mathbb R^n$}\\
   \Rightarrow&\ z^\ast O=\{\lambda^mz^\ast x:m\in\mathbb N_0\}\text{ is dense in $\mathbb C$}\\
   \Rightarrow&\ Z=\{\lambda^m:m\in\mathbb N_0\}\text{ is dense in $\mathbb C$}.
   \end{aligned}

It remains to show that $Y$ and $Z$ aren't really dense in $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ respectively. You may continue from here.

Answer (score -1):

I think the hints in the comments provide you enough help for a simple proof.

You consider two cases: the norm sequence $(||A^n x||)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ either diverges to infinity, or is eventually bounded by some real number $M$ (it could still oscillate and not converge, but we'll see that we don't care).

If it diverges, it means that any open bounded subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ (e.g., $B=\{x\in\mathbb R^n : ||x||<M\}$) contains *at most* a finite number of elements of $O$, which means that $O$ can't be dense in $\mathbb R^n$ (because its closure doesn't even "fill" $B$).
If the norm is (eventually) bounded ($\leq M$), you can use the same argument for $\mathbb R^n\smallsetminus \overline{B}$ (it contains at most a finite number of elements of $O$...).
In either case, $O$ cannot be dense in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Why cannot $(\lVert A^nx\rVert)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ contain both bounded subsequences and divergent subsequences?

Answer (score -1):

There are two cases, either $O$ is bounded, or not. If $O$ is bounded, then it cannot be dense. If it is unbounded, then any subsequence is also unbounded and hence no subsequence has a limit in $\mathbb{R}^n$. This implies that $O$ is closed and hence, not dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Why is it the case that if $O$ is unbounded, then all subsequences are unbounded?

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake. Thank you for pointing out. I imagined a sequence going to infinity in my mind, though it can of course oscillate.